# Measure $\langle \hat{X}\rangle$ and $\langle \hat{Y}\rangle$ from counts

Tags: programming, ibm-q-experience, measurement

I'm confused about how I can measure $\langle \hat{X}\rangle$ and $\langle \hat{Y}\rangle$ using counts. Here's my code for X:

x-basis:

```
# Measurement in x-basis. 
quanc_x = QuantumCircuit(1)
quanc_x.u(1,2,3,0) # prepare some random state
quanc_x.h(0)
quanc_x.measure_all()
quanc_x.draw(output='mpl')
```

```
# number of repetitions
N = 10000

backend = Aer.get_backend( 'qasm_simulator' )
job = execute( quanc_x, backend, shots=N )
result = job.result()

measurement_result = result.get_counts( quanc_x )
print( measurement_result )
plot_histogram( measurement_result )
```

```
cos_phi_est = ( measurement_result['0'] - measurement_result['1'] ) / N  #<--Question
print( "cos(phi) estimated: ", cos_phi_est )
```

My question of this code is marked above. I'm not pretty sure if that looks correct. For Pauli X, we have
$$
\langle \hat{X}\rangle=\langle\psi|0\rangle\langle1|\psi\rangle+\langle\psi|1\rangle\langle0|\psi\rangle
$$
Can I simplify that further? Should that correspond to my code with the question mark? How can I apply that to  $\langle \hat{Y}\rangle$? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That looks right to me.

Since, $HZH = X$ then we have that $\langle \psi | X | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi  | HZH | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi H  | Z |  H\psi \rangle $.

In your code, you generate $|\psi \rangle$ with a $U_3(\theta, \phi, \lambda) $ gate applied to $|0\rangle$. Then you applied the Hadamard gate ($H$) before measuring which is what needed to measure in the $X$ basis as discussed above.

---

For $\langle Y \rangle$ you should note that $(SH)Z(HS^\dagger) = Y $

$$\langle \psi |Y| \psi \rangle = \langle \psi  | (SH)Z (HS^\dagger) | \psi \rangle = \langle \psi SH  | Z |  H S^\dagger   \psi \rangle $$

Thus, here you want to apply $S^\dagger$ follow by the Hadamard gate $H$ before measurement.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I want to find the expectation value from counts, is my code also correct for $X$? (`( measurement_result['0'] - measurement_result['1'] ) / N`)Should that be the same as $Y$?

Comment: Yes. The counts remain the same as you wrote it.

Comment: Thanks, can I understand the measured expectation value as the difference of some probabilities? Why it is not result[`1`]- result[`0`]?

Comment: You already rotate to the computational basis once you apply the rotation $H$ or $H S^\dagger $ to your state $|\psi \rangle$. In the $Z$ basis, $|0\rangle$ has eigenvalue of $+1$ and $|1\rangle$ has eigenvalue of $-1$ since $Z|0\rangle = 1|0\rangle$ and $Z|1\rangle = -1 |1\rangle$.